# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel while calling pages within the site

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a web call that is supposed to do some checking on WSDL pages within the same site. I thought this would be simple. It works fine until we add in the certificate call and then the SSL breaks

```
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate2, chain, errors) => { return true; }
        };

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "fakename.com", false);
        httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(collection);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, token).Result;
```

1. the user clicks the healthcheck link
2. I construct a full uri for the WSDL.
3. the code above runs and I read the respnse.

Unit testing shows this working fine, the difference is that I am making the call outside of the site, from that I can deduce that the certificate does get added, and a call is possible.

Has anyone else seen this happen? Is there some rule I need to observe in order to call a page from within my own site behind SSL?

Comment: Plenty of existing questions on this subject, what have you tried? Most likely your IIS user can't read the private key of the certificate.

Comment: yup... I was using the public key... ARG! but... nobody in the other similar questions ever mentioned that so I missed it

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question...

when I was running the unit tests the call was coming from outside the site and simply used the public .cer file for the client certificate.

when creating the same call from within the site I had to grab the private key file and apply the password.

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(_509FilePath, "my password");
```

I think I would have expected a 403 error rather than the SSL issue, but hey... at least it's working now... thanks @CodeCaster for the hint in the comments